# Python multiprocessing with different constant for each thread

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-rekognition

I want to create a pool with a function calling the boto3 api and using a different bucket name for each thread:

my function is:

```py
def face_reko(source_data, target_data):

        bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    for key in bucket.objects.all():
        key.delete()

    s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=target_img, Body=target_data)
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=source_img, Body=source_data)

    response = reko.compare_faces(
        SourceImage={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucket_name,
                'Name' : source_img
            }
        },
        TargetImage={
            'S3Object' : {
                'Bucket' : bucket_name,
                'Name' : target_img
            }
        }
    )
    if len(response['FaceMatches']) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So basically it deletes all in the bucket, upload 2 new image then use the Rekognition api to compare the 2 images. Since I can't create the same image twice in the same bucket, i'd like to create a bucket for each thread then pass a constant to the function for the bucket name instead of the `bucket_name` const.

Comment: `for key in bucket.objects.all():
        key.delete()`  You really need to come up with a different strategy.  This code will haunt you and serves no obvious purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I've been able to find a way to work around my issue. Instead of maping my function to a pool, I've created a `Worker` class defined like this:

```python
class Worker():
def __init__(self, proc_number, splited_list):
    self.pool = Pool(proc_number)
    self.proc_number = proc_number
    self.splited_list = splited_list

def callback(self, result):
    if result:
        self.pool.terminate()

def do_job(self):
    for i in range(self.proc_number):
        self.pool.apply_async(face_reko, args=(self.splited_list[i],source_data, i), callback=self.callback)
    self.pool.close()
    self.pool.join()
```

So the `Worker` obj is construct with a number of processes and a list of list (`splitted_list` is my main list splited in `number_of_proc`). Then when the `do_job` function is called, the pool starts by creating processes with an id `i` that can be use in the `face_reko` function. The pool stops when `face_reko` returns `True`. To start the `Worker.pool`, just create a `Worker` and call the `do_job` function like so:

```python
w = Worker(proc_number=proc_number, splited_list=splited_list)
w.do_job()
```

Hoping it'll help someone else!